# How can I save turtle output as an image?

Tags: python, svg, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have a code and draw circles. I would like to save the output as image. I am able to save the output as .svg file. But when i try to open, it only shows white page.  I also tried to turn it to .jpg or .jpeg version. Again I see only the white screen. How can I solve the problem?

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint
from svg_turtle import SvgTurtle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of why a minimal example is critcal in debugging. Once you remove all of the irrelevant drawing code, you're left with:

```py
def fiber_circle(fiber):
    # ...
    fiber = Turtle()
    # now start drawing...

# ...
fiber = SvgTurtle(width, height)
fiber_circle(fiber)
# ...
```

You've gone through a lot of trouble to create a `SvgTurtle` `fiber` only to overwrite it with a plain old `Turtle()` instance before you draw anything with it.

Remove `fiber = Turtle()` and use the `SvgTurtle` `fiber` instead.

This creates new problems:

1. Nothing shows up on the screen.
2. Nothing shows up in the SVG.

Problem 1 can be solved by mirroring all `fiber` commands with a `Screen` turtle and may not even matter for your use case. If you don't care about the screen, you can keep it off, or temporarily bring it up to validate your drawing logic by swapping in a `Turtle()` for the `fiber` during development.

Problem 2 seems to be a characteristic in the SVG library which is that it doesn't write sprite positions to SVG. `stamp` rather than `showturtle` works.

Here's a new version that implements these changes with a few simplifications (`map` was overly complex):

```py
from random import randint
from svg_turtle import SvgTurtle
from turtle import Turtle


def fiber_circle(fiber, width, height):
    fiber_r = 35
    fiber_num = 50
    cursor_size = 20
    fiber.hideturtle()
    fiber.color("black")
    fiber.shape("circle")
    fiber.shapesize(fiber_r / cursor_size)
    fiber.speed("fastest")
    fiber.penup()
    fibers = []

    for _ in range(fiber_num):
        fiberr = fiber.clone()
        fiberr.setposition(
            randint(fiber_r - width / 2, width / 2 - fiber_r),
            randint(fiber_r - height / 2, height / 2 - fiber_r),
        )

        while any((a.distance(fiberr) < fiber_r for a in fibers)):
            fiberr.setposition(
                randint(fiber_r - width / 2, width / 2 - fiber_r),
                randint(fiber_r - height / 2, height / 2 - fiber_r),
            )

        fiberr.stamp()
        fibers.append(fiberr)

def write_file(fiber_circle, filename, width, height):
    fiber = SvgTurtle(width, height)
    fiber_circle(fiber, width, height)
    fiber.save_as(filename)

def main():
    write_file(fiber_circle, "fiber.svg", 500, 500)
    print("Done.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much... It really worked but when I convertt to .jpg,.png or .jpeg, it only shows black dots. I also want to see white background. How can i add the code for that? I tried to add screen part but it did not work again. How can I do it? @ggorlen

Comment: No problem. Please make an attempt and open a new question with your updated code showing where you're stuck. How are you making the conversion and what else are you expecting to see than black dots? I'll take a look later today when I have time. Thanks.